# I'm doing a function of inverting values, and the 0, is also inverting, how do I make the 0 not to be negative?

Tags: javascript

Code in Javascript, please help me to make 0 not negative

```
function invertSign(val) {

    return (val * -1);
}

console.log(invertSign(1)) -1
console.log(invertSign(-2)) 2
console.log(invertSign(0)) -0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `|| 0`:

```
function invertSign(val) {
   return -val || 0;
}
```

If `-val` evaluates to -0, it will be a *falsy* value, and so the `||` operator will evaluate to the second operand, which is 0. And so -0 is replaced by 0.

Alternatively, you subtract from 0:

```
function invertSign(val) {
   return 0 - val;
}
```

Here -0 never occurs, because the minus here is not a unary operator, but the binary one. 0 - 0 is just 0, so this may be the simplest solution.

Comment: Can you explain to me what you did for me to understand?

Comment: Added some explanations in the answer. Let me know if something is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is zero, and if it is, then return 0

```js
function invertSign(val) {
    if (val === 0) return 0;
    return (val * -1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an if statement to check if `val === 0`.

```
function invertSign(val) {
    if (val === 0) return val;
    return val * -1;
}

console.log(invertSign(1)); // logs -1
console.log(invertSign(-2)); // logs 2
console.log(invertSign(0)); // logs 0
```